# Cron suddenly calls a script every 15 minutes

Tags: cron

On a Debian server, I have a crontab entry that should call a script every day at 04:21 AM.

That's what it did, until today .. but now the script is called every 15 minutes without any reason !

I have not changed the crontab in months !

Here's the crontab line :

```
21 4 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domain.tld/tasks/hebdomadaire.php &> /dev/null
```

And here's the Apache log ( cat access.log | grep "hebdomadaire" ) :

```
SERVER_IP - - [28/Mar/2016:04:21:01 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [29/Mar/2016:04:21:01 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [30/Mar/2016:04:21:01 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:04:21:01 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:04:36:02 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:04:51:04 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:05:06:07 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:05:21:11 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:05:36:16 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:05:51:22 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:06:06:30 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:06:21:38 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:06:36:47 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:06:51:57 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
SERVER_IP - - [31/Mar/2016:07:07:07 +0000] "GET /tasks/hebdomadaire.php HTTP/1.1" 200 454 "-" "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)"
```

How can that be?

Comment: Do you have any other crontab entries that might be running this `wget` command?  As root, try  `grep '/tasks/hebdomadaire.php' /etc/crontab /etc/cron*/* /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`

Comment: Have you looked in syslog to see if it actually is the cron job running that often?

Comment: Your command gives :
    /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root:21 4 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://www.domain.tld/tasks/hebdomadaire.php &> /dev/null.

Running 'ps' showed a non-stop wget on hebdomadaire.php .. So I killed it, and restarted cron, seems to be fixed.
hebdomadaire is a quite long script, is it possible that cron restarts the script if it takes too long ?

I've added cron log, maybe it will give me clues tomorrow.

Comment: cron log shows that the script is called only once.

But still, the wget is called multiple times, I can't understand why.
The last line of the PHP script sends an e-mail, and since I got an e-mail every 15min, I suppose the PHP script is called multiple times by wget... why ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour of wget ([documented in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options)) is to restart after a default timeout of 900s (aka 15 min).

Adding `--timeout=0` solves the problem here.